# Cant find 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Tags: android

I want to use the `FloatingActionButton` but for that I need the library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

But when I add it to my gradle, I get the message:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':myModule'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myModule:_debugCompile'.
   Could not find com.android.support:design:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
         file:/D:/Development/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
         file:/D:/Development/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
         file:/D:/Development/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
         file:/D:/Development/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         myProject:myModule:unspecified
```

I tried updating my Android SDK but everything is up to date:

[image]

So why can't `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` be resolved?

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.bla.myProject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidcircularcrop_lib')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/eventbus-3.0.0-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: post the your module build.gradle

Comment: Try setting your `buildToolsVersion` to 22.0.1

Comment: added the gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your build file, always set target and compile sdk to the same number. The appcompat lib is also a part of the sdk so when using a 22.x.x support lib, you are goning to need at least the 22 sdk to ensure compatibility, let alone finding the lib. 
Also as Arkadiy suggested it is recommended to use the latest build-tools and gradle version compatible with your android studio.