# Android Studio is giving multiple errors since API 22 updated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting multiple errors in my project, previously it was working fine. I tried may things changing the target api changing dependencies, i dont know why it is not working. Please help me out.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: change support version to 22.2.1,  buildToolsVersion to 22.0.1,  compileSdkVersion to 22 and clean project, see if it helps

Comment: Prokash Sarkar's answer is correct, with a little search you also know why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472549/cant-find-com-android-supportdesign22-2-0/31472892#31472892

Comment: @ThMBc MainActivity errors stills persists

Comment: clean project, rebuild project (under build in menu) and check your imports in the mainactivity file to ensure you are using the correct import for R (you'll need yours (import com.pklabs.rgpvdigest.R or something like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your **build.gradle** file to this,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
.......
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    }
```

Now clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: my gradle errors are gone but the MainActivity errors still persists... :(